# select alternate field name group by postgres

Tags: postgresql

`actor` table schema

```
actor_id | first_name | last_name
```

and I have query

```
select a.actor_id, t.name,count(*) from actor a
LEFT JOIN 
(select fa.actor_id,fa.film_id,c.name  from film_actor fa
LEFT JOIN film_category fc ON fc.film_id=fa.film_id 
INNER JOIN category c ON c.category_id=fc.category_id
ORDER BY fa.film_id) t ON t.actor_id=a.actor_id
GROUP BY a.actor_id, t.name
ORDER BY a.actor_id
```

I am getting result of fields

```
actor_id | name | count
```

I also want to include the `first_name` and `last_name` from `actor` table but i am unable to do it because i can select only those column name which are in group by clause. i want  `first_name` `last_name` in select record without adding it in group by

i want my result as

```
first_name last_name | actor_id | name | count
```

Comment: "_i want  `first_name` `last_name` in select record without adding it in `group by`_" - why? However you can select them using `max()` or `min()` aggregates, like `select a.actor_id, t.name,count(*), max(first_name) as first_name, max(last_name) as last_name from actor a ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just place the columns in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT a.first_name, a.last_name, a.actor_id, t.name,count(*) 
FROM actor a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT fa.actor_id,fa.film_id,c.name  
    FROM film_actor fa
    LEFT JOIN film_category fc 
    ON fc.film_id=fa.film_id 
    INNER JOIN category c 
    ON c.category_id=fc.category_id
    ORDER BY fa.film_id) t 
ON t.actor_id=a.actor_id
GROUP BY a.first_name, a.last_name, a.actor_id, t.name
ORDER BY a.actor_id
```

---

You can use `concat()` or `format()` or the operator `||` to concatenate strings (see [String Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html)), e.g.:

```
SELECT concat(a.first_name, ' ', a.last_name), a.actor_id, t.name,count(*) 
...
```

Comment: is it possible to get concatenated first_name and last_name ?

Comment: Plz checkout string operations.... https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-string.html